# Node JS and Express cannot read data from Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, node-modules

I want to get my data from Mongo DB with Node JS and Express JS. I Already made a mongoose schema and exported the module. But when I'm running the function, I just get an empty JSON object..
here is some code:

This is my exports function:

```
var Buchung = module.exports = mongoose.model('Buchung', buchungSchema);

//Get Buchungen
module.exports.getBuchungen = function (callback) {
    Buchung.find(callback);
};
```

And here's my function to actually get the data:

```
Buchung = require('../DB/models/buchung_mitarbeiter');

router.get('/buchungen', function(req,res){
    Buchung.getBuchungen(function (err, buchung) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
    console.log(buchung);
    res.json(buchung);

    });
});
```

and finally my Schema:

```
var buchungSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user:{
          type: String,
          required: true
      },
    tor:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    datum:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sendungsstruktur:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});
```

I'm greatful for any help!

Comment: can you share your Schema file and also are you sure there is data in your MongoDB, you can check it from MongoDB Atlas:  https://cloud.mongodb.com/user#/atlas/login

Comment: Ok i put it above. I have data in my Collection named "buchung".

Comment: And i'm also just using MongoDB Altas. Is maybe this the problem, that I don't get Data? But I'm Connected to the Atlas Cloud

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code below. please try and let me know if still facing the issue. I have marked with * so remove * before using.

```
Buchung = require('../DB/models/buchung_mitarbeiter');

    router.get('/buchungen', function(req,res){
        Buchung.getBuchungen(function (err, buchung) {
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
        console.log(buchung);
        res.json(buchung);
        **res.send(buchung)**
        });
    });
```

Comment: That is the Model:
`var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Buchung Schema
var buchungSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tor:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    datum:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sendungsstruktur:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});

var Buchung = module.exports = mongoose.model('Buchung', buchungSchema);

//Get Buchungen
module.exports.getBuchungen = function (callback) {
    Buchung.find(callback);
};`

Comment: And this is the call function:
`const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

// Startseite
router.get('/startseite_breuninger', (req, res) => res.render('startseite_breuninger'));

//buchung.js einbinden
Buchung = require('../DB/models/buchung_mitarbeiter');

router.get('/api/buchungen', function(req,res){
    
        Buchung.getBuchungen(function (err, buchung) {
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(buchung);
        res.send(buchung);
    });
});

module.exports = router;`

Answer (score 0):

Export your Schema.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Buchung', buchungSchema);
Buchung = require('../DB/models/buchung_mitarbeiter');

router.get('/buchungen', (req,res) => {
   Buchung.find().then(buchungs => {
     res.json(buchungs);
   }).catch(err => res.json({err})) 
});
`
```

Comment: I exported it as you can see above

Comment: Export only your mongoose model, not the function and after call the method find on that model

Answer (score 0):

```
var Buchung = module.exports = mongoose.model('Buchung', buchungSchema);
module.exports.getBuchungen = function (callback) {
    Buchung.find()
    .then(response => {
    return response; 
    })
    .catch(error => {
    return error;
});
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.